# How To find EditText value using context menu option"Edit"

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext, android-sqlite, android-contextmenu

I am new to android, I am using context menu and I am trying to get EditText values those are saved in database. Please help me below is my code:

```
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Listname);
    Title_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title_Edit);

    content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    Content_Edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.content_Edit);

    duedate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.duedate);

    duedatetext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.duedatetext);

    Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    int content = intent2.getIntExtra("content", 0);

    isEdit = intent2.getBooleanExtra("isEdit", false);

    System.out.println(content + "Intent ID");

    if(isEdit) {
    Database_Notepad db = new Database_Notepad(Add_Task.this);

     Cursor c = db.GetNote(content);

     db.close();

     Title_Edit.setText(c.getString(0));
     Content_Edit.setText(c.getString(1));
     duedatetext.setText(c.getString(2));

     save.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.Updatenote));
```

Context menu Item option:

```
            case R.id.Edit_Note:

                 Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Add_Task.class);
                 Cursor cursor = (Cursor) this.getListAdapter().getItem((int) info.id);
                 cursor.moveToPosition(itemPosition);
                 int content = cursor.getInt(0);
                 intent2.putExtra("content", content );
                 intent2.putExtra("isEdit", true);
                 startActivity(intent2);

                break;
```

Ho do I can get Edittext value if there is any other method please do let me know. thanks.

Comment: So you're just trying to get the value that the user typed into your `EditText` from within the `onContextItemSelected()` method?

Comment: yes Exactly..Please suggest

Comment: we have idea of Data base means how to insert edit text values in data base and how to get that values....

Comment: why are you getting the content as int? It should be `String content = cursor.getString(1);`

Comment: Because it is content id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `EditText` is a member of your class, i.e.:

```
private EditText title = null;

public void onCreate() {
    // ...
    title = findViewById(R.id.yourId);
}
```

You should just be able to do:

```
String titleText = title.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Yes I have done the same. But I am trying to get stored edittext values using contextmenuItem "EDIT" option. how to find that layout where i have stored edittext values

Comment: Oh so you have a `ListView` that contains a bunch of items and you just want to read the value of an `EditText` within the item that was clicked on?